# modeltranslation app doesn't add translated fields in models

Tags: django, django-models, django-modeltranslation

I'm new with modeltranslation and I have a problem. When I do the `manage.py syncdb` command after creating my model and registering the fields to translate in `translation.py` the modeltranslation app doesn't add the translated field to the model. The fields are in the table though. So if I create an object in the python shell I can't access `display_en` because it raises an error

```
AttributeError: 'Content' object has no attribute 'display_en'
```

My settings.py :

```
    DEBUG = True
    TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

    ADMINS = (
         # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
    )

    MANAGERS = ADMINS

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
            'NAME': 'test_db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
            'USER': 'postgres',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
            'PASSWORD': 'admin',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
            'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
            'PORT': '5432',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
          }
     }


     SITE_ID = 1

     TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
     LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr-fr'

     ugettext = lambda s: s

     LANGUAGES = ( 
          ('fr', ugettext('French')),
          ('en', ugettext('English')),
          ('ja', ugettext('Japanese')),
     )


     USE_I18N = True


     TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
     'django.core.context_processors.auth',
     'django.core.context_processors.debug',
     'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
     )

     USE_L10N = True
     USE_TZ = True

     STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
       'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
       'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
       # 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
    )

   # List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
   TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
        'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
        'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    )

   MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
   )

   ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'


   TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
# Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
# Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
# Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
  )

   INSTALLED_APPS = (
       'django.contrib.auth',
       'django.contrib.contenttypes',
       'django.contrib.sessions',
       'django.contrib.sites',
       'django.contrib.messages',
       'django.contrib.staticfiles',
       'tagging',
       #'social_auth',
       'south',
       'django.contrib.admin',
       'sorl.thumbnail',
       'modeltranslation',
       'myapp',
       # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
       # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
     )

     TRANSLATION_REGISTRY = "myapp.translation"
```

My models.py :

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
    from django.conf import settings

    class Test(models.Model):
        display = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('test.display'))
        url = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('test.url'))
```

My translation.py :

```
    from modeltranslation.translator import translator, TranslationOptions

    from myapp.models import Test


    class TestTranslationOptions(TranslationOptions):
        fields = ('display')

    translator.register(Test, TestTranslationOptions)
```

Answer (score 1):

Does modeltranslation load at all? Using the development server `manage.py runserver` prints debug information to `stdout`.

```
Validating models...

modeltranslation: Registered 2 models for translation (Foo, Bar) [pid:12345].
0 errors found
[...]
```

If you don't see this (and you haven't deactivated `DEBUG`) I suppose something goes wrong at import time.

Also which `modeltranslation` version do you use?

The `TRANSLATION_REGISTRY` setting is deprecated since 0.3, which switched to consistent prefixes, so it became `MODELTRANSLATION_TRANSLATION_REGISTRY`.

In 0.4 per-app level translation files were introduced making this setting completely optional. Instead each app is now automatically searched for a `translation.py` in its root directory. At the same time `MODELTRANSLATION_TRANSLATION_FILES` was added. Also being optional it allows to extend the list of translation files.

While support for `MODELTRANSLATION_TRANSLATION_REGISTRY` is kept even in the latest development version to retain backwards compatibility, it is no longer recommended to use it. Instead just put the `translation.py` into the directory of the app you want to translate.

Finally, the `fields` attribute in your `translation.py` is supposed to be a tuple (or list), where you are defining a string. Python will only recognize it as a tuple when you add a comma like this:

```
class TestTranslationOptions(TranslationOptions):
    fields = ('display',)
```

I suppose it's a typo in your question, because I expect `modeltranslation` to bail out if it can't find the fields.

Answer (score 1):

You are using south, so You have to do ./manage.py migrate to translate your fields . Hope this help